# Is there any possible way to force implicit constructor initialization with a string literal

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

Suppose I have a class

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int x);
    Foo(std::string s);
}
```

I want to be able to initialize objects like this

```
int main()
{
    Foo f1 = "some string"
}
```

rather than

```
int main()
{
    Foo f1("some string");
}
```

So far I am getting a compiler error:
error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]|

All I can think of is making an additional constructor that takes char* argument, but I was hoping to avoid this redundancy.

Comment: it's a bad practice. should avoid such implicit conversion.

Comment: Add a constructor `Foo(char const *s)`.  In C++11 you can make this a forwarding constructor to avoid code duplication: `Foo(char const *s): Foo( std::string(s) ) {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it might not seem obvious, there are two user defined conversions in the case of copy-initialization:

```
Foo f1 = "some string";
```

In the expression above, `Foo f1 =` is a call to `Foo(Foo const &)` with the right hand side as argument. For that, the compiler would need to figure out how to go from *literal* (array of N char) to `Foo`, and that requires a user defined conversion to `std::string` (contructor taking `const char*`) and a second user defined conversion from `std::string` to `Foo` (second constructor above).

Now, it might not seem obvious why the second case does not require the same number of conversions… when you do `Foo f("something");` the compiler considers the three overloads:

```
Foo(int);
Foo(std::string);
Foo(Foo const &);
```

There is no conversion from literal to `int`, so the first is discarded. There is a one-step conversion from literal to `std::string` (by means of the constructor taking `const char*`) so this is a viable candidate. As seen above, there is no one-step conversion from literal to `Foo`, so that one is also discarded and the only viable candidate is picked up.

The language is quite clear in that there can only be on user defined conversion in a conversion sequence, so there is nothing that can be done there. So you are left with either providing another constructor or making sure that the right hand side *is* a `std::string`. For that you could either explicitly convert (valid in C++03):

```
Foo f1 = std::string("something");
```

You might also just leave this to the user and require that they do direct initialization instead of copy initialization. Or you can add a constructor that takes the `const char*`.